# How to push a footer to the bottom of page when content is short or missing?

Tags: css, html

I have a page with an outer div that wraps a header, content and footer div.  I want the footer div to hug the bottom of the browser, even when the content div is not tall enough to fill the viewable area (i.e. there's no scrolling).

Comment: main tag => min-hight : 100% or 95%

Answer (score 177):

Your issue can be easily fixed by using flexbox. Just wrap your .container and your .footer in a flex container with a min-height: 100vh, switch the direction to column so that they stack on top of each other, and justify the content with space between so that footer will move to the bottom.

```css
.flex-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-wrapper">
  <div class="container">The content</div>
  <div class="footer">The Footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: For an even cleaner tag layout you can also apply those rules to the body and drop the wrapper container.

Comment: Adding `flex-grow: 1` to the footer might also work well if you just want the footer background to extend to the bottom of the page, but have the footer content right after the container content.

Comment: Drop the `justify-content: space-between` and create a `div` with `flex-grow: 1` where you want the extra space to go.  Agreed with adding to the `body` as well.

Answer (score 51):

While this question is old, I want to improve slightly on the [great answer by Luke Flournoy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51410022/717214).

Luke's answer only works if you have two elements in the wrapper. It's very common to have at least 3: header, main content and footer. With these three elements, Luke's code will space them evenly vertically - most likely not what you want.  With multiple elements, you can do this:

```css
.flex-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.footer {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-wrapper">
  <div class="header">The header</div>
  <div class="content">The content</div>
  <div class="footer">The footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works but it also forces all of the other items on your layout to be involved in the flex flow which isn't always desirable.

Comment: @boylec1986 The question is specifically about header-content-footer setup; if you want something more advanced, you can put the "more advanced" bits inside content.

Comment: You sir deserve a Nobel Peace Prize.

Comment: Would you recommend putting this on the body element? Ex: instead of `.flex-wrapper` class, it's on the `body` element itself. And `.footer` would be on the `footer` tag itself.

Comment: @Jarad no, that won’t work. Flex-wrapper is what takes 100% height of the screen.

Answer (score 22):

What I wanted was to have the footer be at the bottom of browser view ONLY IF the content was not long enough to fill up the browser window (non-sticky).

I was able to achieve by using the CSS function calc(). Which is supported by all modern browsers. You could use like:

```
<div class="container">CONTENT</div>
<div class="footer">FOOTER</div>
```

the css:

```
.container
{
    min-height: 70%;
    min-height: -webkit-calc(100% - 186px);
    min-height: -moz-calc(100% - 186px);
    min-height: calc(100% - 186px);
}
```

Change 186 to the size of your footer.

Comment: For me it works only with VH units - `calc(100vh - 186px)`

Answer (score 15):

Use a blank div with flex-grow:1 to fill unused spaced right before the footer.

```
<body style="min-height: 100vh; display: flex; flex-direction: column;">

  Any content you want, 
  put it here. Can be wrapped,
  nested, whatever.

<div style="flex-grow:1"></div>

<!-- Any content below this will always be at bottom. -->

<footer>Always way at the bottom</footer>
</body>
```

Extract the styles to css as needed. This works by setting <body> as display:flex;

Comment: What I like is there are no wrapping elements necessary

Comment: There's a very good reason why React doesn't touch the `body` tag.  Tread lightly with new ideas, especially if you don't know the reason why the 'big players' aren't doing it.

Comment: Although the React comment is unfounded, the solution works equally well using a div that wraps the content in the body.

Comment: This solution worked for me, although I needed to adjust it a little.

Answer (score 10):

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/AU6yD/

```css
html, body { height: 100%; }

#wrapper { min-height: 100%; height: auto !important; height: 100%; margin: 0 auto -30px; }
#bottom, #push { height:30px;}

body { background:#333;}
#header { height:30px; background:#000; color:#fff; }
#footer { height:30px; background:#000; color:#fff; }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        Header
    </div>
    <div id="push"></div>
</div>
<div id="bottom">
    <div id="footer">
        Footer
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: !important = !yikes

Answer (score 10):

I did what Jahmic up top did (won't let me comment yet) except I had to use VH instead of % since I couldn't just apply it to a container class.

```
#inner-body-wrapper
{
    min-height: 70vh;
    min-height: -webkit-calc(100vh - 186px);
    min-height: -moz-calc(100vh - 186px);
    min-height: calc(100vh - 186px);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can do exactly what you want using Flexbox, as an example will be:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100%;
}

.content {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

as a note the footer must be outside the **content** element

html structure will be something like follow:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <header></header>
            <div class="content">
                <!-- Content -->
            </div>
            <footer></footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i like this one.

Answer (score 7):

I Found this very simple way, just take the main container add min-height and make the footer sticky

```
body { /* the main container */
  min-height: 100vh;
}

footer {
  position: sticky;
  top: 100%;
}
```

There are great answer above, i think the problem is that nowadays most people whant to do this with some framework like React, Next or Vue, these frameworks add another element to wrap all the html rendered by the framework like divs with an id `#root #__next`
so we have to aply the style to that element

Answer (score 3):

To make it work responsively when the footer is taller on mobile devices compare to on desktop, you can't really know the footer height. One way to do it is to stretch the footer out to cover the entire screen.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  min-height: 80%;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #cccccc;
  box-shadow: 0px 500px 0px 500px #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">Main content</div>
<div class="footer">Footer</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Best solution to have this done was a previous reply from @DR-MATTH, assuming that the body is the main container:

```
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
    
footer {
  position: sticky;
  top: 100%;
}
```

I just wanted to add that I had to use this variation `min-height: calc(100vh - "any margin top/bottom of any sibling element above the footer");` to make the footer really sticky at the bottom when the page have not enough content and avoiding unnecessary scrolling.

Something like this:

```
body {
    min-height: calc(100vh - 60px);
}

footer {
    position: sticky;
    top: 100%;
    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```html
body{
    position:relative;
    min-height:100vh;
}
footor{
     position:absolute;
    bottom:0%;
    width:100vw;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's always better to describe your code or how it is different from the other answers.

Comment: This works. Best solution here! I never knew about `bottom: 0%`. I'm glad that I still look at answers that aren't the most popular (yet).

Answer (score 0):

I tried: http://jsfiddle.net/AU6yD/ as here it's the best  option but I had problems when the content of the `<div id="wrapper">` started to get too big see
[evidence.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgLnh.png), what I did to solve this was refreshing the body size everytime I changed the content of that div like this:

```
var body = document.body,
html = document.documentElement;
body.style.height = 100 + "%";
setTimeout(function(){
   var height = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight,
                          html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, 
                          html.offsetHeight );
   body.style.height = height + "px";
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this [codepen.io/dendii/pen/LLPKJm](//codepen.io/dendii/pen/LLPKJm) media responsive

```css
html, body {
  color:#fff;
}
.wrapper{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
.main{
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.main-inner {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}
article,aside{
  float:left;
  padding:20px 10px;
}
article{
  width:70%;
  background:darkred;
}
aside{
  width:30%;
  background:darkblue;
}
.top {
  padding:20px 10px;
  height:100%;
  background:darkgreen;
}
.bottom,.text-mid {
  padding:20px 10px;
  height:100%;
  background:darkorange;
}
.text-mid {
  margin-top: auto;
  background:darkgrey;
}
@media (max-width: 768px){
  .main-inner{
    display: block;
  }
  article,aside{
    width:100%;
    float:none;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <header class="top">
      <h1>Header</h1>
    </header>
<div class="main"><div class="main-inner">
  <article>
    blank content
  </article>
  <aside>
    class sidebar
  </aside>
</div></div>
<div class="text-mid">
    <div class="center">
        Whatever you want to keep.
    </div>
</div>
<footer class="bottom">
    <div class="footer">
        Footer
    </div>
</footer>
 </div>
```

Another alternative if you want a main-wrapper to adjust the screen [EqualHeight](//codepen.io/dendii/pen/JJjjmp)

Answer (score 0):

I've solved same problem with jquery

```
    var windowHeiht = $(window).height();
    var footerPosition = $("#asd-footer").position()['top'];

    if (windowHeiht > footerPosition) {
        $("#asd-footer").css("position", "absolute");
        $("#asd-footer").css("bottom", "0");
        $("#asd-footer").css("width", "100%");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Reworking the jQuery solution. I have it working with resizing the window. When the window is bigger than the page, the footer style's position is "absolute" fixed at the bottom the window. When the window is smaller than the page, the footer stays at the bottom of the page - scrolling off the bottom.

```html
<style>
    .FooterBottom {
        width:100%;
        bottom: 0;
        position: absolute;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        FooterPosition();

        $(window).resize(function () {
            FooterPosition();
        });
    });

    var originalFooterBottom = 0;

    function FooterPosition() {
        var windowHeight = $(window).height();
        if (originalFooterBottom == 0) {
            var footer = $("#Footer");
            originalFooterBottom = footer.position()['top'] + footer.height();
        }

        if (windowHeight > originalFooterBottom) {
            var footerElement = document.getElementById("Footer");
            if (!footerElement.classList.contains('FooterBottom')) {
                footerElement.classList.add('FooterBottom');
            }
        }
        else {
            var footerElement = document.getElementById("Footer");
            if (footerElement.classList.contains('FooterBottom')) {
                footerElement.classList.remove('FooterBottom');
            }
        }

    }
</script>
```

I tried many style only solutions but none of them worked. This Javascript/Style solution works just fine for me, even with its odd mix of jQuery and GetElement.

Thanks to Asad for his post.

Answer (score 0):

i had just changed the position to sticky and set top to 100%.Then i go to its parent block and set its min height is 100%
This solved my problem.

In my case the parent block was body so i changed the min height of body.

```
.footer {
position: sticky;
top: 100%;
text-align: center;    
width: 100%;
height: 60px;
background-color: #1abc9c;}


body{
margin:0;
padding:0;
min-height:100vh;}
```

Answer (score 0):

To push a footer to the bottom of the page when content is short using **tailwind**.

Add the following to a class

> flex flex-col justify-between min-h-screen

```
    <div className="flex flex-col justify-between min-h-screen">
        <div>
           ... //your body here
        </div>

        <Footer/> // your footer here
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

In my website i have 3 seperation divs div-header,div-body,div-footer. i put
min-height for div-body using javascript(i used window.height()) . so when content is low then it will maintain minimum height.so that the footer always be in bottom.

Comment: <div class="div-header"></div>
<div class="div-body" style="min-height:1000px;"></div>
<div class="div-footer"></div>

for min height, you can use window.height() in javascript

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

I tried this and it works fine so far

```
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
width:100%;
```

or

```
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
left:0;
right:0;
```

Answer (score -2):

Wrap your footer with a class as following:

```
<div class="footer">
<h1>footer content</h1>
```

Then add following css properties to the footer:

```
.footer{
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
```

}

Answer (score -4):

This is what I am doing for my page

```html
<h6 style="position:absolute; bottom:0;">This is footer at bottom of page without scrollbars</h6>
```

Comment: If there is div covering the whole page the proposed footer will not be pushed to the bottom, instead, it will stay where it is.