# What to do when website's "too short" and there's an empty space below footer?

Tags: html, css, layout, frontend

### Introduction

I've seen many, many, great websites made by best front-end developers but there's this issue on most (if not all) of the sites having footers. What's the best, cross-browser, technique that keeps footer in the right place?

### Cool "header - content - footer" layout:

[image: Layout - OK]

### Broken layout (happens when site's "too short"):

[image: Layout - Broken :(]

Everything is usually fine on smaller screens, but this is pretty frequent in 1680x1050 or FullHD resolutions.

### Partial fixes

- absolute positioning of the footer, but this will only move the gap above the footer, to the content section, what looks better in many cases, but still sucks.
- creating really long footers but let's assume in this case we want it to have height of 20 pixels only.
- changing `body { background:` to the color of the footer will make it look less uglish, but the gap will be there, still.
- probably some JavaScript tricks like getting window's height and changing position/size of some elements, but sounds like an overkill.

### Working fixes

Looks like it's still the best to make sites long enough to fit even the biggest screens (well, pretty obvious).

---

Does this issue have any name? I couldn't find anything on SO and I'm sure people were asking this question before. Do you have any ideas how to handle this problem, maybe there are some smart fixes, tricks that I'm not aware of?

Thanks!

Comment: You could use a fixed footer.

Comment: What's wrong with the CSS Sticky Footer technique?

Comment: There's no problem with absolute / fixed positioning the footer and setting minimum height on the content. It's a well laid out and presented post but I don't think it's actually a problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to push a footer to the bottom of page when content is short or missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575826/how-to-push-a-footer-to-the-bottom-of-page-when-content-is-short-or-missing)

Answer (score 2):

apply the css to the content section :

```
#content{
    min-height:600px;
}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it's not very responsive. What if the vertical resolution of a screen is a lot higher than 600px? A sticker would still not be at the bottom of a page

Answer (score 2):

### Way 1: Using flexbox

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="content">content</div>
  <footer>footer</footer>
</body>
```

### Way 2: Adjusting the size of (non-footer) container with `calc()`:

Assuming you want a fixed-size footer of size 50px:

```css
.content {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 50px);
}
.footer {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="content">content</div>
  <footer class="footer">footer</footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with absolute positioning:

```
#footer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Or another more complex way is to use javascript and set the Footer's `margin-top` to `body height - all element's height`

Answer (score 0):

Make the footer have this as CSS:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Markup:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="footer">...</div>
</div>
```

That will position at the bottom. If you want space, add a margin on the bottom (`margin-bottom: xxxpx;`).

Answer (score 0):

which means 100% of view height

```
<div class="container" style="min-height: 100vh;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the height of the footer the window height minus the height of your application.

example in react.js

```
let footerHeight = window.innerHeight - 678 /*my "too short" application height*/;

<footer style={{height: footerHeight }}>
</footer>
```

Now the background will grow depending on the extra space.